# Network topology in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, networking, graph, topology

I'm trying to define a network topology in C/C++ language. The goal is to parse it from C/C++ to XML and viceversa. In this topology (as you see in the picture) routers are connected with interfaces; each of them have an ip address and a link capacity.
Are there classes (like graphs) or structs to implement easier a network topology?

[image: topology]

Comment: You want to "parse C++ to XML"? And why don´t you write some own data classes for your use case? Not everything is the standard lib...

Comment: In C++ it doesn't matter, the only difference between a `class` and a `struct` is the default member visibility (`private` versus `public`). And in C it's a moot point since C doesn't have classes. And would say that *any* topology is a graph.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg not in math ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network topology is simply a graph.

The most popular representations of the graph are adjacency list/matrix. Adjacency list node has the following structure (for ex.):

```
template <class T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    std::vector<Node*> childs;
};
```

If you later want to use graph algorithms, better use adjacency matrix [Adjacent matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509982/adjacent-matrix?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good C++ XML parser API's out there, see: [What XML parser should I use in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c)

There are also plenty of good networking libraries out there, see: [Best C/C++ Network Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library)